# can't see nohup command's output when used with ssh

Tags: linux, unix, nohup

I am trying to run a jar onto a different server. So, in my current script I do ssh on that server, and then run the jar using nohup. But, nohup.out is not getting created on the new server. So, I am not able to catch errors.

If, I log into that server manually and then fire the jar, nohup.out gets created. Can someone please help with this?

Below is the command that I've written in my script:

```
sshpass -p $node_pwd ssh -n root@$node "sh -c 'cd mydir;nohup java -jar NodeStarter.jar config.properties > /dev/null 2>&1 &'"
```

Here, **node** is the server I am logging into.
**node_pwd** is the variable containing the password for that server.

Answer (score 0):

```
nohup java -jar blah.jar > /dev/null 2>&1
```

In this example, you are redirecting your output from stderr to stdout, but you have *already* redirected your output from stdout to /dev/null.

The result is that you are piping both stdout and stderr to /dev/null

Output only goes to nohup.out if it has not already been redirected.

It is likely you are not using the same redirection parameters when running the command from the shell.

Comment: I tried running the command without redirecting the output to /dev/null, but still nohup.out is not created.

Comment: Maybe it writing To a nohup.out in your home directory rather than mydir, and you are looking in mydir?  At least some versions of nohup will use nohup.out in $HOME if the standard output is not a terminal.

Comment: I ran a find command for nohup to search for it in every dir and I could not find it.
 But, if I run the jar manually by logging onto that particular server, nohup.out is created.
Any reason why this is happening?